# Uploading File Contents to a Textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to enter the location of a file, or Upload a file into a webpage, and have the webpage type out its contents as the value of a `<textarea>`. I have no idea where to begin. What should I try?

Comment: For this, you do not need to _upload_ the file, you can just read the content of the file in your app. But when it comes to the changed version, then it starts to get confusing; how are you tracking the change? Is it git?

Comment: Use the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload). Example shown in docs easily modified to insert as textarea value

Comment: What exactly **have** you tried? Does uploading work already?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have been searching in a lot of sites how I would do this. I haven't been able to begin. as afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan has mentioned, it's not uploading, I just need the apps to reaqd the contents and display the contents of that file in a textarea. Lets say I don't "track the change" and just have the file be displayed for now.